# Choosing projection for distance calculations in Alaska?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states

I am working within the entire state of Alaska and slightly into western Canada, and I need a projection which will allow me to accurately calculate distances between points within the state. Currently I've been using ESPG 2964, which is an equal area projection, which is therefore no good.

I was feeling a little overwhelmed looking at Google so does anyone have a relatively simple answer?

Comment: What software are you using / have access to? Look for "geodesic distance" or "haversine" or "great circle distance" here and in a search engine.

Comment: @mkennedy, I am using Google earth engine to do the projection (since I have a LOT of points), and R to do the distance calculations. The R package just looks for the distance between two points in whatever units/projection your data is in. It is a really simple package which works on the large amount of data that I have. But it means that I need to have all my data in a good projection first. Any ideas?